# PayPal checkout html form not working

Tags: html, paypal-sandbox, paypal

i have some difficulties with defining html form for PayPal checkout,

i always use the same code but this time something go wrong,

i'm trying to send the user for paypal page to pay the all cart at once and

i'm getting an error:

> We cannot process this transaction because there is a problem with the PayPal email address supplied by the seller. Please contact the seller to resolve the problem. If this payment is for an eBay listing, you can contact the seller via the "Ask Seller a Question" link on the listing page. When you have the correct email address, payment can be made at www.paypal.com.

i checked the account setting and it seems to be ok, Account Type: Business Status: Verified, i also add the ipn address in the account and turn it to ON

this is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal" name="paypal">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> 
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="business@email.com‏"> 
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="ILS"> 
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/orderSubmited.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/paid.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.example.com" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="payment>
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123456" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="250" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="Address" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="City" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="Zip" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="customer@email.com" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="CustomerFirstName" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="CustomerLastName"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: check to see if your'e using a sandbox email account for the business